# JAR not being included in classpath

Tags: java

In my working directory I have the following files : mallet-deps.jar, TopicTest.java and trove-3.0.3.jar but when i run `javac -cp mallet-deps.jar:. TopicTest.java` I get a bunch of import errors saying package doesn't not exist i.e

TopicTest.java:3: package cc.mallet.util does not exist
import cc.mallet.util.*;

It seems like the Jar is not being included properly, im compiling on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: what platform? Are you compiling on a windows machine?

Comment: Windows? Try `;` instead of `:`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need a manifest file that will point to the jar. use ClassPath:

Comment: Please elaborate your answer, see [answer].

Answer (score 0):

what version of java do you use?
does the reffered jar file really contain the package reported as missing?